# Comparison function using rvalues

Tags: c++, tuples, comparison, rvalue-reference

Here's an attempt to make a custom comparator for the class `Foo`. It will apply some transformations to the members then lexicographically compare them:

```
struct Foo {
    std::string s;
    float x;
    std::vector<int> z;
    std::unique_ptr<std::deque<double>> p;

    friend bool operator<(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) {
        auto make_comparison_object = [](const Foo& foo) {
            return std::forward_as_tuple(
                foo.s,
                -foo.x,
                std::accumulate(
                    foo.z.begin(),
                    foo.z.end(),
                    0),
                foo.p ? std::make_optional(*foo.p) : std::nullopt);
        };
        return make_comparison_object(lhs) < make_comparison_object(rhs);
    }
};
```

Although elegant, there is a problem here: the rvalue references, e.g. the reference to the result of `-foo.x`, do not sufficiently extend the lifetimes of the rvalues they point to; they will be destroyed at the end of the lambda. Therefore the `return make_comparison_object(lhs) < make_comparison_object(rhs);` will access dangling references and cause undefined behavior.

I can see two ways around this:

- Use `std::make_tuple` instead of `std::forward_as_tuple`. This will work, but I am concerned that it may incur additional copies or moves, in particular I think it might copy any lvalues passed to `std::make_tuple` such as `foo.s`.
- Inline the contents of the lambda, like this:

  ```
  return std::forward_as_tuple(
          lhs.s,
          -lhs.x,
          std::accumulate(
              lhs.z.begin(),
              lhs.z.end(),
              0),
          lhs.p ? std::make_optional(*lhs.p) : std::nullopt)
      < std::forward_as_tuple(
          rhs.s,
          -rhs.x,
          std::accumulate(
              rhs.z.begin(),
              rhs.z.end(),
              0),
          rhs.p ? std::make_optional(*rhs.p) : std::nullopt);
  ```

This also works, but it looks terrible and violates DRY.

Is there a better way to accomplish this comparison?

Edit: Here's some test code comparing the proposed solutions:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

#define BEHAVIOR 2

struct A {
    A(int data) : data(data) { std::cout << "constructor\n"; }
    A(const A& other) : data(other.data) { std::cout << "copy constructor\n"; }
    A(A&& other) : data(other.data) { std::cout << "move constructor\n"; }

    friend bool operator<(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) {
        return lhs.data < rhs.data;
    }

    int data;
};

A f(const A& a) {
    return A{-a.data};
}

struct Foo {
    Foo(A a1, A a2) : a1(std::move(a1)), a2(std::move(a2)) {}

    A a1;
    A a2;

    friend bool operator<(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) {
        #if BEHAVIOR == 0
        auto make_comparison_object = [](const Foo& foo) {
            return std::make_tuple(foo.a1, f(foo.a2));
        };
        return make_comparison_object(lhs) < make_comparison_object(rhs);
        #elif BEHAVIOR == 1
        auto make_comparison_object = [](const Foo& foo) {
            return std::make_tuple(std::ref(foo.a1), f(foo.a2));
        };
        return make_comparison_object(lhs) < make_comparison_object(rhs);
        #elif BEHAVIOR == 2
        return std::forward_as_tuple(lhs.a1, f(lhs.a2))
             < std::forward_as_tuple(rhs.a1, f(rhs.a2));
        #endif
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo1(A{2}, A{3});
    Foo foo2(A{2}, A{1});
    std::cout << "===== comparison start =====\n";
    auto result = foo1 < foo2;
    std::cout << "===== comparison end, result: " << result << " =====\n";
}
```

You can try it on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/M81HMEFl6wfoiV4b). The results are consistent on both gcc/clang, and make sense considering what goes into the construction of the tuples:

- `std::make_tuple`: 2 copies, 2 moves
- `std::make_tuple` with `std::ref`: 0 copies, 2 moves
- `std::forward_as_tuple` inlined: 0 copies, 0 moves

Comment: Before worrying about performance, worry about *correctness*. Then benchmark your code to see if it's even worth worrying about performance - many times it is not, since the code executes fast enough and is not used in any path hot enough to matter.

Comment: I believe that [RVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) should take away your fears about using `std::make_tuple`.  And I agree with the comment above, too.

Comment: Of course, correctness first, micro-optimizations later. But comparing tuples is a very common pattern and if a "right way" exists, combining simplicity with performance, then I'd obviously like to find out. As for RVO, I know it exists but I don't know the intricacies well enough to see if it applies here. Certainly RVO optimizes the copy of the tuple. But will it elide the construction of the tuple, which necessarily may involve copies?

Comment: @Arcinde To make a permalink at Wandbox, hunt down and click on the 'Share' button.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up using the "inline `std::forward_as_tuple`" method, but with a macro to make things more DRY:

```
  friend bool operator<(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) {
#define X(foo)                                            \
  std::forward_as_tuple(                                  \
      (foo).s,                                            \
      -(foo).x,                                           \
      std::accumulate((foo).z.begin(), (foo).z.end(), 0), \
      (foo).p ? std::make_optional(*(foo).p) : std::nullopt)

    return X(lhs) < X(rhs);
#undef X
  }
```

Advantages:

- doesn't incur any unnecessary copies or even moves
- don't have to worry about writing `std::ref` in the right places
- is safe, as rvalue references are used before the end of the full-expression
- can often be used to define `operator<` and `operator==` in one go (just "scope" the macro around both functions"
- makes interesting use of `std::forward_as_tuple`: it "forwards" the arguments to `std::tuple<Types&&...>::operator<` so it's (sort of) used for its intended purpose

Disadvantages:

- macros ugly

Comment: You're right, sort of.  It does work (I checked) but the reason is because the _temporaries_ created by the two calls to `std::optional` are only destroyed at the end of the full expression.  It's nothing to do with rvalue references and it's important that you understand this.  I find the example itself rather artificial.  There wouldn't normally _be_ any need to create any temporaries to implement `operator <`.  If there is then the class itself is probably poorly designed.

Comment: The use of `std::forward_as_tuple` as a convenience to compare the members of a complex object is interesting and that's what drew me to this question, but if you get rid of the temporaries then you can go back to the lambda (just so long as you add a comment saying 'create no temporaries in here') and ditch the macro.  If you _do_ need a temporary then the macro would be your only choice (if you insist on using 
 std::forward_as_tuple, which I'm not sure I would).  And moves are cheap.

Comment: You are correct that it would've been more accurate for me to say "temporaries" instead of "rvalue references", but that is a minor nit. And you may think the example is artificial but it was the entire point of the question. Certain members may not be comparable and one may need to transform them to comparable types via a mapping function, creating temporaries. Using `std::make_tuple` (with or without `std::ref`-wrapping lvalues) are indeed other valid solutions, just not the one I chose after my considerations.

Comment: Oh my.  It's hardly a 'minor nit' because it's important to understand what was wrong with your original code (which it looks like you do now) and to do that more generally you have to stop playing fast and loose with the terminology.  And OK, there might be times when implementing `operator<` might best be done by constructing temporaries, sure, but if that's the point you're trying to make then a simpler example  (one that transforms a string in some way, perhaps, before comparing the transformed version) would serve that purpose _much_ better than what you have posted here, sorry.

Comment: Did you miss the part in the OP where I wrote: "Although elegant, there is a problem here: the rvalue references, e.g. the reference to the result of `-foo.x`, do not sufficiently extend the lifetimes of the rvalues they point to; they will be destroyed at the end of the lambda. Therefore the `return make_comparison_object(lhs) < make_comparison_object(rhs);` will access dangling references and cause undefined behavior." Terminologically speaking, yes, I should have said "do not sufficiently extend the lifetimes of the *temporaries* they point to." But I understood the general idea.

Comment: Still and all, this is still quite a neat idea, if one can accept that macro (which doesn't bother _me_ too much, personally) and I can see you put a lot more effort into it this time around, so kudos for that.  So if you can clean it up a bit (I'll settle for you explaining the fact that it's _the temporary created by `std::make_optional`_  that stops you from using a lambda here and therefore makes the macro necessary) then I'll reverse my downvote.

Comment: No, I saw that, and it's good stuff.  But _`-foo.x` is not a temporary_, it's a primitive type, so there are no lifetime issues with that at all.  I analysed your real problem in some detail at the end of my answer.

Comment: Here you are simply wrong, see https://wandbox.org/permlink/EznHGZp1kvRTryYI. `-foo.x` is clearly a temporary since it is the result of the function call expression `operator-(int x)`.

Comment: You've demonstrated significant lack of understanding, with your newbie-like misuse of `std::move`, your incorrect use of `std::ref` on a stack variable that wasn't suggested by anybody, the present issue of `-foo.x`, and the fact that your answer didn't contain any new information not already expressed in my original post or in xskxzr's answer. So please don't try to lecture me further with your condescending attitude.

Comment: What _are_ you talking about?  `int` is a primitive type, `operator-` simply doesnt come into it.  And it was xskxzr who introduced `std::ref`, not me, and it was all wrong. I included it in my answer (along with `std::move`) for the sake of completeness _because that's what we do here_, and a little  credit for that would be welcome, actually. And yes, I have a lot to learn, we all do, and I'm not ashamed of that, _but so do you_.  Don't lose sight of that, just because you are pissed at me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::make_tuple` with `std::ref`:

```
auto make_comparison_object = [](const Foo& foo) {
    return std::make_tuple(
        std::ref(foo.s),
     // ^^^^^^^^
        -foo.x,
        std::accumulate(
            foo.z.begin(),
            foo.z.end(),
            0),
        foo.p ? std::make_optional(*foo.p) : std::nullopt);
};
```

Comment: The rvalues still need to be moved into the tuple, but the copies are the most expensive part, so this is pretty good.

Comment: @Arcinde `std::ref` won't work in the context of your original question (and you're lucky that it doesn't) because it doesn't capture the temporary - please see my rewritten answer.

Comment: @PaulSanders I really appreciate the effort. However I think you are misunderstanding some of the suggestions. (1) The use of `std::ref` suggested here should wrap *only lvalues*. That is why it's used on `foo.s`, for example, and not `-foo.x`, which would be a compiler error. When used on lvalues, it avoids the copy upon calling `std::make_tuple`. (2) The use of `std::forward_as_tuple` is UB when placed in the lambda, but I believe that when inlined directly as `return std::forward_as_tuple(...) < std::forward_as_tuple(...)` it is innocuous.

Comment: @PaulSanders (3) Finally the use of `std::move` in your answer doesn't actually do anything; `make_A (foo)` is already an rvalue.

Comment: @Arcinde Not at all. Regarding point 3, sure, but I already said that.  Please take the time to **properly** study my [MCVE].  I think you will find I know what I'm talking about, especially the final paragraph of the summary at the end.  Write a _proper_ test program that _actually uses a lambda_ and prove it to yourself, if needs be (because you haven't), but I have already done that for you.

Comment: @Arcinde I updated my answer to make `std::ref` compile.  As you can see, using it doesn't achieve anything.  In particular, it most definitely does not capture the temporary, as my results show.  I also added an analysis of your original code, which, if you want to get your head around all this, you should read.  Your understanding of the fundamentals is seriously lacking here and if you don't put that right you are going to come unstuck with code like this.

Comment: Now I've put a lot of work into this (because I was interested in learning about tuples, mostly), so you should do me the courtesy of reading my answer properly and then voting accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174298/discussion-between-arcinde-and-paul-sanders).

Comment: @Arcinde Why?  I've said all I have to say, it's your turn to put some work in now.  Please post any additional comments back to my answer - I imagine xskxzr is getting a little bored with this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Rewritten answer, I have given the problem proper consideration this time (even though my original answer was correct).

**tl;dr** For heaven's sake don't return a pointer or reference to a stack-based variable from a function or method, however fancy the code might look.  That, essentially, is all this question is about.

Let's start with a test program which, in my eyes, constitutes a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

#define USE_MAKE_TUPLE  0
#define USE_STD_FORWARD 2
#define USE_STD_REF     3
#define USE_STD_MOVE    4
#define BEHAVIOR        USE_STD_MOVE

struct A {
    A(int data) : data(data) { std::cout << "A constructor (" << data << ")\n"; }
    A(const A& other) : data(other.data) { std::cout << "A copy constructor (" << data << ")\n"; }
    A(A&& other) : data(other.data) { std::cout << "A move constructor (" << data << ")\n"; }
    A(const A&& other) : data(other.data) { std::cout << "A const move constructor (" << data << ")\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "A destroyed (" << data << ")\n"; data = 999; } 

    friend bool operator<(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) {
        return lhs.data < rhs.data;
    }

    int data;
};

struct Foo {
    Foo(A a1, A a2) : a1(std::move(a1)), a2(std::move(a2)) {}

    A a1;
    A a2;

    friend bool operator< (const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs)
    {
        auto make_comparison_object = [](const Foo& foo)
        {
            std::cout << "make_comparison_object from " << foo.a1.data << ", " << foo.a2.data << "\n";
#if BEHAVIOR == USE_MAKE_TUPLE
            return std::make_tuple (make_A (foo), 42);
#elif BEHAVIOR == USE_STD_FORWARD
            return std::forward_as_tuple (make_A (foo), 42);
#elif BEHAVIOR == USE_STD_REF
            A a = make_a (foo);
            return std::make_tuple (std::ref (a), 42);
#elif BEHAVIOR == USE_STD_MOVE
            return std::make_tuple (std::move (make_A (foo)), 42);
#endif
        };

        std::cout << "===== constructing tuples =====\n";
        auto lhs_tuple = make_comparison_object (lhs);
        auto rhs_tuple = make_comparison_object (rhs);
        std::cout << "===== checking / comparing tuples =====\n";
        std::cout << "lhs_tuple<0>=" << std::get <0> (lhs_tuple).data << ", rhs_tuple<0>=" << std::get <0> (rhs_tuple).data << "\n";
        return lhs_tuple < rhs_tuple;
    }

    static A make_A (const Foo& foo) { return A (-foo.a2.data); }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo1(A{2}, A{3});
    Foo foo2(A{2}, A{1});
    std::cout << "===== comparison start =====\n";
    auto result = foo1 < foo2;
    std::cout << "===== comparison end, result: " << result << " =====\n";
}
```

Now the issue is clearly capturing the temporary created by calling `make_A()` within the body of the lambda in the tuple returned by `make_comparison_object`, so let's run some tests and look at the results for different values of `BEHAVIOUR`.

First up, BEHAVIOUR = **USE_MAKE_TUPLE**:

```
===== constructing tuples =====
make_comparison_object from 2, 3
A constructor (-3)
A move constructor (-3)
A destroyed (-3)
make_comparison_object from 2, 1
A constructor (-1)
A move constructor (-1)
A destroyed (-1)
===== checking / comparing tuples =====
lhs_tuple<0>=-3, rhs_tuple<0>=-1          <= OK
A destroyed (-1)
A destroyed (-3)
===== comparison end, result: 1 =====
```

So that worked, and there were no extra copies (although there were a few moves, but then you need those).

Now let's try BEHAVIOUR = **USE_STD_FORWARD**:

```
===== comparison start =====
===== constructing tuples =====
make_comparison_object from 2, 3
A constructor (-3)
A destroyed (-3)
make_comparison_object from 2, 1
A constructor (-1)
A destroyed (-1)
===== checking / comparing tuples =====
lhs_tuple<0>=0, rhs_tuple<0>=0            <= Not OK
===== comparison end, result: 0 =====
```

This, as you can see, is a disaster, the temporaries are gone by the time we try to access them.  Let's move on.

Now BEHAVIOUR = **USE_STD_REF**:

```
===== comparison start =====
===== constructing tuples =====
make_comparison_object from 2, 3
A constructor (-3)
A destroyed (-3)
make_comparison_object from 2, 1
A constructor (-1)
A destroyed (-1)
===== checking / comparing tuples =====
lhs_tuple<0>=0, rhs_tuple<0>=0            <= Not OK
===== comparison end, result: 0 =====
```

Same result, which doesn't surprise me at all.  After all, we returned a reference to a variable on the stack.

And finally, BEHAVIOUR = **USE_STD_MOVE**.  As you can see, the results are the same as just calling `std::make_tuple` without the move - as you might expect when constructing an object from a temporary:

```
===== constructing tuples =====
make_comparison_object from 2, 3
A constructor (-3)
A move constructor (-3)
A destroyed (-3)
make_comparison_object from 2, 1
A constructor (-1)
A move constructor (-1)
A destroyed (-1)
===== checking / comparing tuples =====
lhs_tuple<0>=-3, rhs_tuple<0>=-1          <= OK
A destroyed (-1)
A destroyed (-3)
```

So, to summarise, just use `std_make_tuple`, as I posted originally.

Note that you have to be super careful with `std::ref`.  **All it does** is make a reference copyable.  It's still a dangling pointer under the skin if the reference itself goes away while you're still using the wrapper, as it does here.

And as I said at the start, this whole thing boils down to not returning a pointer (or a reference) to an object on the stack.  It's just all wrapped up in fancy clothes.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/twGvIe7oHPNZ3o3B).

---

**Update** - a better analysis of the OP's original post.

Let us look at what the OP actually puts in his tuple:

```
auto make_comparison_object = [](const Foo& foo) {
    return std::forward_as_tuple(
        foo.s,
        -foo.x,
        std::accumulate(
            foo.z.begin(),
            foo.z.end(),
            0),
        foo.p ? std::make_optional(*foo.p) : std::nullopt);
```

So, what is he putting in there? Well:

- `foo.s` comes from the parameter passed into the lambda, so that's OK
- `-foo.x` is a primitive type, so that's OK too
- with the code as written, `std::accumulate` return an `int`, so again we're OK
- `std::make_optional` constructs a temporary, so **that's *not* safe**

So, that code isn't in fact safe, but not for the reason the OP states, and @xskxzr's answer doesn't actually contribute anything.  As soon as you want to export a non-primitive temporary constructed inside a lambda (or indeed any other type of function) - by whatever means - you have to do it properly, and was it ever thus.  *That's* what I'm trying to get across here.

Comment: See my edit to the question. Standard RVO will elide the copy of the tuple, but won't optimize away its construction. The constructor of a tuple of values necessarily calls the copy constructor if it's passed an lvalue.

Comment: @Arcinde Updated my answer.  When you consider _all_ the factors involved, `std::make_tuple` is the right solution here.